# gmpy source code

Tags: python, primes, gmp

Is there any way I can look at the source code of `gympy`?
To be specific, `gmpy2.is_prime`.

I tried various links

- https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/source/checkout
- https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc
- https://github.com/qsnake/gmpy

I can't find it anywhere.

I have gmpy2 downloaded, and checked on my local drive, but the file extension was `.pyd`.
When I open it (in Notepad), the following is the first few lines I see -

```
MZ       ÿÿ  ¸       @                                   ð   º ´  Í!¸LÍ!This program     cannot be run in DOS mode.
```

The rest is gibberish.

I want to write a very fast prime-checker, and its the best I've come across so far
Can anyone tell me how I can get at the source code? Or perhaps links to some other fast prime-checker's source code (or discussions)?

Comment: since all the files I can see in that repository are .c or .h (and since it makes sence to write such a lib in c or c++ rather than python), I don't think you can look at the python code doing what you want to see, since I don't think there is any

Comment: [gmpy](https://github.com/aleaxit/gmpy), [GMP](https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I maintain gmpy and gmpy2. @cartman and @DJV already directed you to the source code but I'll add a few comments.

`mpz_probab_prime_p` does trial factoring and then multiple iterations of the Miller-Rabin test. The Miller-Rabin test doesn't prove that a number is prime, it is just very good at proving that a number is composite. If you repeat the test sufficiently many times, the odds are that the number is prime. There are known instances where the `mpz_probab_prime_p` reports that a composite is prime when only 12 to 15 iterations are done.

A more interesting primality test is the BPSW test. There are no known composites that are reported as prime but it conjectured that they exist.

`gmpy2` also contains several primality algorithms that can be used as building blocks for a complete test. They are based on the code found at:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpzlucas/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpzprp/

Some useful links:

http://www.trnicely.net/misc/bpsw.html

http://www.pseudoprime.com/pseudo.html

Answer (score 3):

It maps to `Pympz_is_prime` C function, see [this link](https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/source/search?q=Pympz_is_prime&origq=Pympz_is_prime&btnG=Search%20Trunk) for the source code for the function.

Comment: And actually this is a wrapper for `mpz_probab_prime_p`, which can be found in GMP source `mpz/pprime_p.c`